# How to create a PDF-out-of-Sphinx-documentation-tool

Tags: pdf, python-sphinx

Followed this link to try and generate pdf from Sphinx:

https://www.quora.com/How-to-create-a-PDF-out-of-Sphinx-documentation-tool

```
$ sphinx-build -b pdf source build/pdf

Error: Cannot find source directory  `/Users/seb/mydocs/source'.


$ make all-pdf
make: *** No rule to make target `all-pdf'.  Stop.
$ make pdf
make: *** No rule to make target `pdf'.  Stop.
```

Since tried in OSX:

```
$ conda install -c dfroger rst2pdf=0.93
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
  - rst2pdf 0.93*
```

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

```
anaconda search -t conda rst2pdf
```

EDIT:

After pip install rst2pdf

```
install rst2pdf
register rst2pdf in your conf.py Sphinx config
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc','rst2pdf.pdfbuilder']
```

But adding 'rst2pdf.pdfbuilder' causes

```
Extension error:
Config value 'math_number_all' already present
make: *** [html] Error 1


$ sphinx-build -bpdf sourcedir outdir
```

But what do I specify as sourcedir and outdir? Example please.

EDIT:

Now after make html

and then:

```
 $ rst2pdf index.rst output.pdf
 index.rst:14: (ERROR/3) Unknown directive type "toctree".

 .. toctree::

 :maxdepth: 2
```

introduction
   tutorial
   multiple_jobs
   deployment
   project

```
index.rst:26: (ERROR/3) Unknown interpreted text role "ref".
index.rst:27: (ERROR/3) Unknown interpreted text role "ref".
index.rst:28: (ERROR/3) Unknown interpreted text role "ref".
```

Also:

```
$rst2pdf.py index.rst -o mydocument.pdf
```

Does produce a mydocument.pdf but completely different from html and toc to all the pages are not even there?

[Image of pdf verse HTML same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR0AI.png)

Comment: Why do you use anconda/conda? If you don't have a specific reason for this, install pip and run "pip install rst2pdf". If you want to have more control over the style of your output, it's better to build the PDF via LaTeX.

Answer (score 38):

This is from the [official Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html#running-the-build). If you have `pdfTex` tool installed in your machine, all you need is:

```
$ make latexpdf
```

Then, the generated pdf file(s) will be under `_build/latex/<PROJECT-NAME>.pdf`

So, the complete process from scratch would be as follows:

```sh
$ pip install -U sphinx # install the package
$ sphinx-quickstart # create a new project (answer the questions)
$ make latexpdf # compile and generate pdf file
```

Note that you may also "optionally" install whatever extensions needed by editing the file `config.py`

**NOTE**: This answer assumes LaTeX engine is installed on your machine.

Comment: Yeah this is a much better answer than using 'rst2pdf'. Also, just a quick note 'latexmk' needs to be installed, so a 'sudo apt install latexmk' may be necessary (which was the case for me).

Comment: Note that this answer requires Latex tools to be installed on your system, which may not be trivial depending on your OS: https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/

Comment: True, thanks. My bad I thought "If you have pdftext tool .." implied that. But I guess I should be more explicit.

Comment: Note that `latexmk` is in the `texlive-binextra` package on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 25):

I have succeeded in generating a PDF file for the DevStack document by following the configuration changes [in this link](https://www.quora.com/How-to-create-a-PDF-out-of-Sphinx-documentation-tool/answer/Vimalkumar-Velayudhan?srid=Jpsp):

Here are the steps:

1. Edit your `conf.py` (edit or append values)

   ```
   extensions = ['rst2pdf.pdfbuilder']
   pdf_documents = [('index', u'rst2pdf', u'Sample rst2pdf doc', u'Your Name'),]
   ```
2. Install the "[`rst2pdf`](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf)" if necessary

   ```
   pip install rst2pdf
   ```
3. Build the PDF file like this:

   ```
   sphinx-build -b pdf doc/source doc/build
   ```

Comment: Sadly the quora link is no longer valid.

Comment: The source code of the package `rst2pdf` contains multiple `SyntaxErrors` in python 3.7.

Comment: As of September 2019, the latest release `rst2pdf` does not support Python 3, but the master branch does. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/issues/796) to track a Python 3-compatible release.

Comment: `rst2pdf` is resurrected and is available at https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf.  It supports Python 3.  See this for more information https://gist.github.com/alfredodeza/7fb5c667addb1c6963b9

Comment: How can I use the sphinx-build command to generate PDF with rst2pdf custom styles. Currently the command: rst2pdf index.rst -s paamrstyles.txt creates only single PDF.

Comment: Sadly rst2pdf does not properly support **equations**: https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/issues/1028#issuecomment-1593322989

Answer (score 9):

Succeeded in Pdf Generation via Latex (for windows 10)... No need to change existing conf.py file in Sphinx... the best solution is install MiKTeX....install Perl (ActiveState).... after when running sphinx type 'make HTML' type 'make latex' and then make latexPdf... this solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you my brother. Your explain is clair. It work as well for me after many breakdown compilation with readthedoc.org. Thank very much.

Answer (score 4):

You could avoid rst2pdf and use `make pdflatex` to build pdf output via a latex file.

cf more info:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/sphinx/AdvancedUsersManual/RenderingPdf/

Comment: Fior `make pdflatex` to work for Unicode characters, the TeX environment in the platform should be set appropriately. Also, perhaps the language statment like `language = 'XXX'` is needed in `conf.py`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have a look at http://rst2pdf.ralsina.me/handbook.html#sphinx.

Following applies to Ubuntu 16.

But it is probably less painful to install a full LaTex suite than to try to get this tool running; it is very sensitive to errors, and is difficult to use.

I took a look there (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373) and it looks daunting...

this is more encouraging: https://milq.github.io/install-latex-ubuntu-debian/

And I did it:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
make clean latexpdf
```

is worthwhile your patience (and disk space) to install. I got rid of rst2pdf.

Comment: as an aside, you should NOT use ubuntu texlive install, rather install texlive directly from https://www.tug.org/texlive/

Comment: thank you. it is sometimes painful to find out where the truth lies in Stackoverflow...

Comment: I just went through this entire exercise I&#39;m going to create a video and a detailed answer here, on how to properly create PDFs nice-looking PDFs from restructuredtext

Answer (score 1):

[Found this related post](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2499) which discovers that **rst2pdf** breaks math rendering in **Sphinx 1.4.1** because it imports a dummy math module.

> In `rst2pdf.pdfbuilder:setup()`, it calls `mathbase.setup()` internally to  install dummy math module. It causes conflicts and raise errors.

I had this same error when running `sphinx-build -b pdf`

> Extension error: 
>   Config value 'math_number_all' already present

Now looking at **latex** option, and exporting to pdf as @tfv posted. [`pdflatex` is a larger universe of TeX distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49570/119382).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to latexpdf: [rinohtype](https://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/)

Once rinohtype is installed, `sphinx-build -b rinoh . _build`

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `documentation.md`, and open it in Typora software. Navigate to the Sphynx documentation that you need, mark with mouse and copy inside Typora. Then inside typora export as PDF. Done.

Answer (score 0):

cd into the folder where the makefile is and `make latex` worked out ok